# ID of record created with force:recordData, the Lightning Data Service

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

How can I get the ID of a record being inserted with force:recordData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `recordId` property will be populated with the ID of the new record once it's created.

The solution is not hard to find, it's [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordData.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Bind a record Id to the object, and you should be able to get it back out:

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}" ...
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.recordId}" action="{!c.recordSaved}" />
```

Or, you can get the value after force:recordSaveSuccess from the recordId attribute:

---

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordData" ...
```

---

```
var recordData = component.find("recordData").get("v.recordId");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call the saveRecord method on the recordData component from javascript...

```
createNewExam : function(component, event, helper){
    component.find("ClonedExamCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
```

it is given an object of type RecordSaveResult as a callback. From this object get simply use recordID attribute.

```
let newExamID = saveResult.recordId;
```

Answer (score 1):

saveResult.recordId is correct;
state -> SUCCESS
recordId -> a23O00000012YREIA2
error -> undefined
entityApiName -> OrderInfo__c
entityLabel -> OrderInfo
action -> SecureObject: [object Object]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }